# Not breaking out of for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

For some reason, when the candidate number reaches 21, it realises 21 is divisible by 3, but then won't break out of the for loop/ By contrast, for example for 25, is notes 25 is divisible by 5 then breaks out.

It seems specifically, when div == 3, it doesn't break out of the loop. Why is this?

```
for cand in range (3,100):
    if cand%2 != 0:
        if ((cand ==3) or (cand ==5) or (cand ==7) or (cand ==11) or (cand == 13)):
            print str(cand) + ' is prime.'
        else:
            x = sqrt(cand)
            y= int (x)
            for div in range(3, (y+2)):
                if (cand%div == 0):
                    print div
                    print str(cand) + ' is divisible by' + str(div)
                    div = 10*y
                elif (div == y):
                    print str(cand) + ' is prime.'
```

Here's the output of the code:

```
3 is prime.
5 is prime.
7 is prime.
3
9 is divisible by3
11 is prime.
13 is prime.
3
15 is divisible by3
17 is prime.
19 is prime.
3
21 is divisible by3
21 is prime.
23 is prime.
5
25 is divisible by5
3
27 is divisible by3
27 is prime.
29 is prime.
31 is prime.
3
33 is divisible by3
33 is prime.
5
35 is divisible by5
37 is prime.
3
39 is divisible by3
39 is prime.
41 is prime.
43 is prime.
3
45 is divisible by3
5
45 is divisible by5
45 is prime.
47 is prime.
7
49 is divisible by7
3
51 is divisible by3
51 is prime.
53 is prime.
5
55 is divisible by5
55 is prime.
3
57 is divisible by3
57 is prime.
59 is prime.
61 is prime.
3
63 is divisible by3
7
63 is divisible by7
5
65 is divisible by5
65 is prime.
67 is prime.
3
69 is divisible by3
69 is prime.
71 is prime.
73 is prime.
3
75 is divisible by3
5
75 is divisible by5
75 is prime.
7
77 is divisible by7
77 is prime.
79 is prime.
3
81 is divisible by3
9
81 is divisible by9
83 is prime.
5
85 is divisible by5
85 is prime.
3
87 is divisible by3
87 is prime.
89 is prime.
7
91 is divisible by7
91 is prime.
3
93 is divisible by3
93 is prime.
5
95 is divisible by5
95 is prime.
97 is prime.
3
99 is divisible by3
9
99 is divisible by9
```

Comment: I can't see a `break`, `return` or `raise`. When are you expecting it to break out of either for loop and why?

Comment: so, I'm looking at the second for loop. If the cand%div produces no remainder, the div number is multiplied by 10, and therefore by my warped logic it should no longer by in range 3,(y+2). This logic seems to hold when the div number is anything other than 3...

Comment: @Ravin python for loops don't work that way. If you want to break use `break`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A for loop is not a while loop.

In Python, the only type of for loop is what in other languages is 'foreach' - it iterates through a list of elements. In your case, you're iterating through a range, ie a list of integers from 3 to y+2. It's the number of elements in the list that determines when the iteration stops, not the value of any one of them. When you change `div` within one iteration of the loop, that has no effect on the rest of the items.

You can use `break` to break out of the loop if a condition is met. Or if you want to keep your logic, you could try using `while` instead, but then you'll need to increment the counter manually.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a `break` statement anywhere in your code.

Comment: ok - so a break fixes the problem (thanks by the way), but shouldn't the loop automatically break when the div goes out of range of the loop?

Comment: @Ravin: Both of your loops start at 3. Why would 3 be out of a range that starts at 3?

Answer (score 1):

Python loops don't work that way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
for a in range(1,20):
        print a
        a = 39
```

Consider:

```
for a in [32,14,"a",False]:
        print a
        a = True
```

For example.

Answer (score 1):

> By contrast, for example for 25, is notes 25 is divisible by 5 then
>   breaks out.

No, it doesn't. It also runs the loop for div=6, but nothing is printed because none of the `if` conditions hold. Your `for` loop sets the index at the start of every iteration, so your `div=10*y` line is completely meaningless.